# Router detects my Nessus scan and kicks me off the network

Tags: network, network-scanners, nessus

I'm trying nessus on a public router.

When I run a scan on the router at `10.0.0.1`, the router somewhat detects it and proceeds to kick me off. If I put `targets : 10.0.0.2-10.0.0.255` (scann all except the router), I'm not kicked off.

Any way to bypass that? I need to scan the router.

Comment: Have you tried using a stealthy (less aggressive) scan?

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: The make and model of the router might be helpful to see if the router lists a feature like the one you describe

Comment: @jrtapsell I don't have access to the router but one time my nessus scan lasted long enough so that it could detect it uses a MikroTik RouterOS (Critical : MikroTik RouterOS < 6.41.3 SMB Buffer Overflow). But the SMB port is disabled so I can't really use this exploit.

Comment: There is no way to know what the protections are in order to know how to get around those protections. Try configuring your scan to be less aggressive. Consult the Nessus documentation for how to configure scans.